# need VBA to work on all tabs

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code that works, but it only works on a specific excel tab.
This code only works when I have the "Failure Codes" tab open. I would like this to execute regardless of what tab I am on.
When debugging the line that starts with {ComboBox1.List=} what is highlighted in yellow. If you can modify the last line so that it will no longer need to be restricted to that specific tab, that would be great.
Other than that everything works!

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
Dim IDRow As Range
Dim LastCol  As Long

Set IDRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Failure Codes").Range("AA:AA").Find(ComboBox3.Value)
If Not IDRow Is Nothing Then
    LastCol = Cells(IDRow.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ComboBox1.List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(IDRow.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Resize(ColumnSize:=LastCol - 1).Value)  ' this line is highlighted in yellow when debugging
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The code fires when you update `ComboBox3` - surely the combobox is only on one sheet? That sheet will need to be active to fire the code.

Comment: Specify a worksheet for `Cells(IDRow.Row, …` like `Worksheets("Failure Codes").Cells(IDRow.Row, …` • If that doesn't help please tell which error you get and where or what happens instead of what you expect to happen.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to maintain the ComboBox1.List reflecting the data in the "Failure Codes" worksheet, even if another tab is active? Or that you want the ComboBox1.List to reflect the data from the tab currently active?

Comment: Combobox1 and combobox3 are part of a userform1 located on a tab called "Reject Tags"
I want to maintain the ComboBox1.List reflecting the data in the "Failure Codes" worksheet, even if another tab is active ("Reject Tags").

Run-time error 1004
Aplication-defined or object-defined error

Comment: @Have you tried removing the `.Value`? The Transpose function may require the input to be ranges, not values. If that's not the issue, you will need to provide more information on the type of error/error message you're getting.

Comment: I have not tried moving the .Value; I don't know where to move it too.
Error:
Run-time error 1004 Aplication-defined or object-defined error

Comment: What is the value of `LastCol` if the error occurs? And what is `IDRow.Address` you can use `Debug.Print IDRow.Address` to get that.

Comment: Sorry, I screwed up. I placed the "Debug.Print IDRow.Address, LastCol" on the wrong line. 
IDRow.Address= "$AA:$91" LastCol = 1

Comment: Well, that's the issue `LastCol = 1` then you try to `Resize(ColumnSize:=LastCol - 1)` which is `0` and a column count/width of `0` is not possible to resize to. Did you do what I said in comment #2 above and specify the worksheet for the `Cells`?

Comment: `Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
    Dim IDRow As Range
    Dim LastCol  As Long
    Set IDRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Failure Codes").Range("AA:AA").Find(ComboBox3.Value)
    Debug.Print IDRow.Address, LastCol
    If Not IDRow Is Nothing Then
        LastCol = Worksheets("Failure Codes").Cells(IDRow.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ComboBox1.List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(IDRow.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Resize(ColumnSize:=LastCol - 1).Value)
    End If
End Sub`

Comment: I figured out what you were talking about in the second comment. I got it to work. Thank you, everyone, for your help!